# One request opens multiple pages

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have a problem that is not easy to summarize in title of the question. Here's the situation:

There is one very simple form that contains only one  for selecting a xml and one submit button. When I submit this form, some work is done and I get org.w3c.dom.Document. This Document contains all information I need. Until now controller that was handling this, was returning page that renders this xml.

What I want to do now is except rendering xml, I want to display one or more pages that will contain some date that is inside this xml. Of course, depending of how many particular items there is in that xml, that much additional pages I will display, but I don't think it would be more than 3 or 4 in worst case scenario.

Any suggestion would be helpful, if this is even a possible.

Comment: _was returning page that renders this xml_ Return a different page.

Comment: No, it was the same page.

Comment: If you want a different UI, you're going to have make a different UI. One that shows the xml and also has labels or what-have-you that shows the date. If you want to access this page from the same URL, you're going to have to return something else from the controller.